# `set -u` (nounset) vs checking whether I have arguments

Tags: bash

I'm trying to improve this [nasty old script](https://github.com/SELinuxProject/selinux/blob/5ed45797df92494a137e16eafb64d54490b1d0d5/policycoreutils/scripts/fixfiles).  I found an undefined variable error to fix, so I added `set -u` to catch any similar errors.

I get an undefined variable error for "$1", because of this code

```
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
     process "$command"
```

It just wants to know if there are arguments or not.   (The behaviour when passed an empty string as the first argument is not intended.  It won't be a problem if we happen to fix that as well).

What's a good way to check whether we have arguments, when running with `set -u`?

The code above won't work if we replace "$1" with "$@", because of the special way "$@" is expanded when there is more than one argument.

Comment: Related: [BashFAQ #112](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/112). (`set -u` is not as controversial as `set -e` -- see [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) there -- but it's still not by any means universally acknowledged as a Good Thing).

Comment: That's fine. It's my baby for the time being. Proper testing would be nice, but eh. I need to see if there are any _more_ undefined variable errors beyond the first one.  I don't mind that I have to refactor the style to be a bit more pedantic in order to avoid false positives; I prefer the pedantically correct behaviour (as per my answer).  Parts of the code are already written in very `set -u` friendly ways.  Absolutely I don't expect this code to work with `set -e`, at that point I might as well rewrite it in python.

Comment: Consider http://shellcheck.net/ (which, yes, is downloadable, installable, command-line-invocable software) , if your goal is finding typo'd variable names.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`$#` contains the number of arguments, so you can test for `$1`, `$2`, etc. to exist before accessing them.

```
if (( $# == 0 )); then
    # no arguments
else
    # have arguments
fi;
```

Comment: If `IFS` contains `0` (or any numeric character that's present in the expansion), this will behave badly due to the lack of quotes. Consider using a numeric context instead, since the question is tagged bash: No context will alter how `$#` is interpreted in `(( $# == 0 ))` .

Answer (score 14):

You can ignore the automatic exit due to `set -u` by setting a default value in the parameter expansion:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -u
if [ -z "${1-}" ] ; then
    echo "\$1 not set or empty"
    exit 1
fi
echo "$2"    # this will crash if $2 is unset
```

The syntax is `${parameter-default}`, which gives the string `default` if the named parameter is unset, and the value of parameter otherwise. Similarly, `${parameter:-default}` gives `default` if the named parameter is unset or empty. Above, we just used an empty default value. (`${1:-}` would be the same here, since we'd just change an empty value to an empty value.)

That's a [feature of the POSIX shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) and works with other variables too, not just the positional parameters.

If you want to tell the difference between an unset variable and an empty value, use `${par+x}`:

```
if [ "${1+x}" != x ] ; then
    echo "\$1 is not set"
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

My personal favorite :

```
if
  (($#))
then
  # We have at least one argument
fi
```

Or :

```
if
  ((!$#))
then
  # We have no argument
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$#`, the number of arguments.  This provides the most consistent handling for empty arguments.

You might also see the use of `"$*"`.  It is similar to `"$@"`, but it is expanded differently when there are multiple arguments.

```
a() {
    for i in "$@"; do echo $i; done
}
b() {
    for i in "$*"; do echo $i; done
}
c() {
    echo $#
}
echo "a()"
a "1 2" 3
echo "b()"
b "1 2" 3
echo "c()"
c "1 2" 3

# Result:
a()
1 2
3
b()
1 2 3
c()
2
```

Comment: `$*` gives the wrong result when an empty string is passed as argument.

Comment: As an aside -- I'd suggest avoiding the `function` keyword, which makes your code incompatible with POSIX sh, but adds no value over the standard-compliant syntax (which is just `a() {`, with no preceding `function`).

Answer (score 0):

If each positional argument has a fixed meaning, you can also use this construct:

```
: ${1:?Missing first argument}
```

If the first positional argument isn't set, the shell will print "Missing first argument" as an error message and exit. Otherwise, the rest of the script can continue, safe in the knowledge the `$1` does, indeed, have a non-empty value.